# how do i iterate over an accordion in vaadin?

Tags: java, iterator, accordion, vaadin

I would like to do something like this:

```
Iterator<Component> componentIterator = accordion.iterator();
    while (componentIterator.hasNext()) {
        Accordion c = (Accordion) componentIterator.next();
        System.out.println("test: " + c.getCaption());
    }
```

but the "c" variable is always null, so, the question is, how can i get the caption of a tab inside the accordion?

Thanks.

EDIT: MChaker, here it is!

```
    @PostConstruct
public void posInit() {
    VerticalLayout layoutGeral = LayoutFactory.vertical();

    TabSheet tabSheet = new TabSheet();
    tabSheet.setCaption("Editar");
    tabSheet.setWidth(ConstantesUI.CEM_POR_CENTO);
    tabSheet.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);

    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

    addTabsToAccordion(accordion);

    accordion.setWidth(1170, Unit.PIXELS);
    accordion.setHeight(600, Unit.PIXELS);

    if (accordion != null && accordion.getCaption() != null) {
        if (accordion.getCaption().equals("Configurações Gerais")) {
            accordion.setWidth(1200, Unit.PIXELS);
            accordion.setHeight(240, Unit.PIXELS);
        }
    }

    tabSheet.addComponent(accordion);

    final Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.setHeight(550, Unit.PIXELS);
    panel.setScrollLeft(0);

    panel.setContent(tabSheet);

    layoutGeral.addComponent(LayoutFactory.titulo("Propriedades"));
    layoutGeral.addComponent(LayoutFactory.conteudo(panel, new HorizontalSplitPanel(), addSaveButton()));

    addComponent(layoutGeral);

    setSizeFull();
}
```

The `addTabsToAccordion` method:

```
accordion.addTab(buildTabEmail(this.props), "Email");
```

The `buildTabEmail`method:

```
private FormLayout buildTabEmail(Map<String, Propriedades> props) {

    // definição dos campos
    this.servidor = TextFieldFactory.simples("Servidor:", 20);
    this.porta = TextFieldFactory.simplesNumerico("Porta:", 5);
    this.usuairoEmail = TextFieldFactory.simples("Usuário:", 15);
    this.passwordEmail = PasswordFieldFactory.simples("Senha:", 10);
    this.emissorMensagem = TextFieldFactory.simples("Emissor da Mensagem:", 30);
    this.sslPort = CheckBoxFactory.marginTop5("SSL");
    this.tlsPort = CheckBoxFactory.marginTop5("TLS");


    // adição ao mapa
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILPORT, new VO(porta, props.get(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILPORT)));
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILEMISSOR, new VO(emissorMensagem, props.get(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILEMISSOR)));
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILSENHA, new VO(passwordEmail, props.get(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILSENHA)));
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILUSER, new VO(usuairoEmail, props.get(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILUSER)));
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILHOST, new VO(servidor, props.get(PropsHandler.CONST_EMAILHOST)));
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.EMAIL_TLS, new VO(tlsPort, props.get(PropsHandler.EMAIL_TLS)));
    this.configMap.put(PropsHandler.EMAIL_SSL, new VO(sslPort, props.get(PropsHandler.EMAIL_SSL)));

    preencheDadosEdicao();

    FormLayout tabEmail = new FormLayout();
    tabEmail.addComponent(servidor);
    tabEmail.addComponent(porta);
    tabEmail.addComponent(usuairoEmail);
    tabEmail.addComponent(passwordEmail);
    tabEmail.addComponent(emissorMensagem);
    tabEmail.addComponent(sslPort);
    tabEmail.addComponent(tlsPort);

    return tabEmail;
}
```

Comment: What does `addTabsToAccordion` method do?

Comment: i just posted it above, the method `buildTabEmail` returns a `FormLayout`, is this work if i change the return type to `Panel` instead of `FormLayout`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help MChaker, i coudn't solve my problem using the Accordion component, but i solve it using multiples tabSheets, and it is more flexible and beauty then an accordion. Thank you again and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
TabSheet tabsheet= new TabSheet();
// Create an example of tab
VerticalLayout tabExample= new VerticalLayout();
tabExample.addComponent(new Embedded(null,
       new ThemeResource("anyImage.jpg")));
tabExample.setCaption("Example");
tabsheet.addTab(tabExample).setIcon(
        new ThemeResource("anyIcon.png"));


Iterator<Component> componentIterator = tabsheet.getComponentIterator();
while (componentIterator.hasNext()) {
    Component c = (Component) componentIterator.next();
    Tab tab = tabsheet.getTab(c);
    System.out.println("test: " + tab.getCaption());
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, my code returns 10 results (i have 10 tabs on my accordion) but your code returns 0 (zero).

Comment: Can you post how have you defined the `accordion` variable?

Comment: This code will get every TabSheet, but it'll not get the tabs inside the accordion, is that right? I'd like to iterate over the accordion's tabs.

Comment: i'm looking for something like `accordion.getTabs()` (returns a collection), that will solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help MChaker, i coudn't solve my problem using the Accordion component, but i  solve it using multiples tabSheets, and it is more flexible and beauty then an accordion. Thank you again and sorry for the bad english.